# React + TypeScript: Passing components in an Array as props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am looking for a solution in TypeScript React to pass multiple components in an array. I have declared interfaces and importing it inside my component. But it gives me an error as 'Type 'Element' has no properties in common with type 'IDataView''.

I have added code snippet to what steps i am following. I am not sure what am i missing in the below code.

My Parent Component:

```
    const DataViewContainer:React.FC = () => {
 return (
    <ViewCollection views={[<BarChart />, <LineChart />]} />
 )
}
```

Child Component  :

```
interface IViewCollection {
 views: IDataView[]
}
interface IDataView {
 barChartView?: React.ReactNode;
 lineChartView?: React.ReactNode;
}

const ViewCollection = (views: IViewCollection): JSX.Element => {
 return (
    <Carousel>
       {views.map((cmp) => { return (cmp) }}
    </Carousel>
 )
}
```

Comment: This looks like a bit of an [xy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem#:~:text=The%20XY%20problem%20is%20asking,trouble%2C%20you%20ask%20about%20Y.) question. What are you trying to do with those elements? Do you just want to render them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your type, you suppose to pass an object. Notice the fixes of `props`, `views` and the usage inside `ViewCollection` component.

```
const DataViewContainer: React.FC = () => {
  return (
    <ViewCollection
      views={{ barChartView: <BarChart />, lineChartView: <LineChart /> }}
    />
  );
};

const ViewCollection = (props: IViewCollection): JSX.Element => {
  return (
    <Carousel>
      {props.views.barChartView}
      {props.views.lineChartView}
    </Carousel>
  );
};
```